# Calculate time difference while executing query

Tags: mysql

Query :

```
SELECT products.product_name ,
employee.emp_name,employee.emp_code,process.process_name,timer_completed.worked_qty , 
FROM_UNIXTIME(timer_completed.start/1000,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') as start,
FROM_UNIXTIME(timer_completed.end/1000,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') as end , 
FROM timer_completed
INNER JOIN com_jobcard ON com_jobcard.id = timer_completed.job_card_id
INNER JOIN products ON products.id = com_jobcard.product_id    
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id = timer_completed.employee_id
INNER JOIN process ON process.id = timer_completed.process_id
INNER JOIN carat_percentage ON carat_percentage.id = com_jobcard.carat_id
INNER JOIN groups ON groups.id = timer_completed.group_id
INNER JOIN departments ON departments.id = groups.dept_id
AND departments.id = '40';
```

OUTPUT :

```
JCID-1151521    PRNG    ARAVINTHAN.N        A4942   Brushing           0    07-07-2015 14:35:10     07-07-2015 14:43:45     
JCID-1149968    SRNL    Sathya              A4535   Correction          29  07-07-2015 18:06:28     07-07-2015 18:32:33     
JCID-1149968    SRNL    Sathya              A4535   Inside_Correction   29  07-07-2015 18:32:45     07-07-2015 18:42:44     
JCID-1149968    SRNL    Pani Paul Prakash   A3100   Lapping          30     08-07-2015 09:16:20     08-07-2015 09:16:46     
JCID-1149968    SRNL    Pani Paul Prakash   A3100   Nice             30     08-07-2015 13:14:36     08-07-2015 13:37:50
```

Dear friends from the following query I'll get the result as given below , but my expected result is I've to sum the values of SUM (timer_completed.worked_qty) so that the start time and end time has to be subtracted and the values has to be sum parallel .
I'll use group by employee.emp_code so the worked qty has to be sum and for each iteration the start time and end time has to be subtracted 
((07-07-2015 18:32:45) -(07-07-2015 18:42:44))and finally the sum of worked qty and time taken has to be given as result

expected result is

```
JCID-1151521    PRNG    ARAVINTHAN.N        A4942   Brushing           0   0:0:35
JCID-1149968    SRNL    Sathya              A4535   Correction          58  0:23:47
JCID-1149968    SRNL    Pani Paul Prakash   A3100   Lapping          60     0:3:50
```

Comment: you can use TIMESTAMPDIFF, SUM, GROUP BY clauses

Comment: what is the field name of (A4942,A4535,A3100)?

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

Replace the following code

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(timer_completed.start/1000,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') as start,
FROM_UNIXTIME(timer_completed.end/1000,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') as end ,
```

With

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, FROM_UNIXTIME(timer_completed.start/1000,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'), FROM_UNIXTIME(timer_completed.end/1000,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')) as res
```

feel free for comment

Answer (score 0):

USE TIMESTAMPDIFF and GROUP BY and SUM MySQL function.

I edited your whole query(assuming A4942,A4535 are process.ids)

```
SELECT products.product_name, employee.emp_name,employee.emp_code,
process.process_name, 
SUM(timer_completed.worked_qty),SUM(timer_completed.start -timer_completed.end) as res, 
FROM timer_completed
INNER JOIN com_jobcard ON com_jobcard.id = timer_completed.job_card_id
INNER JOIN products ON products.id = com_jobcard.product_id    
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id = timer_completed.employee_id
INNER JOIN process ON process.id = timer_completed.process_id
INNER JOIN carat_percentage ON carat_percentage.id = com_jobcard.carat_id
INNER JOIN groups ON groups.id = timer_completed.group_id
INNER JOIN departments ON departments.id = groups.dept_id
AND departments.id = '40'
GROUP BY process.id;
```

Comment: edited my answer. you will get timestamp diff in seconds now

Comment: what is the data type of timer_completed.start and  timer_completed.end ?

Comment: oops.. then you don't need to use TIMESTAMPDIFF. Please update the question with table structure and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93563/discussion-between-sumit-pandey-and-user1894647).